# Orthogonal basis of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a two part question of which I have a semi-correct answer and can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

Let $\textbf{u}=(-2,1)$ and $\textbf{v}=(1,1)$

*i) Show $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ form an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ wrt inner product 
$\langle\textbf{u},\textbf{v}\rangle=2u_1v_1+u_1v_2+u_2v_1+5u_2v_2$. Use this basis to find an orthonormal basis by normalizing each vector.*

First I showed $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ formed a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ by row reduction to get $2\times2$ identity matrix.

Second I showed $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are orthogonal using the given inner product space and found that $\langle \textbf{u},\textbf{v}\rangle=0$

Third I normalised each vector to get $\|\textbf{u}\|=3$ and $\|\textbf{v}\|=3$ to give unit vectors for $\textbf{u}$ to be $\textbf{a}=(-2/3,1/3)$ and $\textbf{v}$ to be $\textbf{b}=(1/3,1/3)$.

*ii) Express vector **w**=(1/3,4/3) as a linear combination of the orthonormal basis vectors obtained in part i.*

To find linear combination of the two vectors I let **w**=$c_1$**a**+$c_2$**b** then solved to get $c_1=1$ and $c_2=3$ . These coefficients aren't correct because when I check and sub values in I get **w**=$c_1$**a**+$c_2$**b**=(-2/3,1)+3(1/3,1/3)=(1/3,2)
but the answer should be **w**=(1/3,4/3) after substituting.

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the last step, you've miscopied $a$: it should be $(-2/3, 1/3)$ instead of $(-2/3, 1)$. Your work is just fine aside from that.

Comment: Also: Nice work explaining what you'd tried and what was giving you trouble!